# Getting NaN error in Processing when Xbee is used and trying to create a popup window.

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee, processing-lang

I am trying to get data from D6T Omron thermal sensor. It works fine with both Arduino and Processing when I connect it to pc directly. However, it seems to always cannot read my last data in my data array when i use Xbee on them. It results in a NaN for my last data in my array in processing display [Fig 1].

Anyone having any thoughts on this? Any help will be much appreciated! =D

Another problem i having here is that i was trying to make a popup window when my sensor senses a sum of 34*4 in the center pixels with no success currently. The last data in the array returns in NaN error again and the program is not responding after that. [Similar with Figure 1.] D:

It actually works fine until we reach this stage "Serial.write(0x03)" from Arduino to processing when it senses a sum of 34*4 in the center. I am confused. Any idea on how to improve that? =) Thanks a lot in advance!

Attached below is my code (Arduino sketch):

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <WireExt.h>

#define D6T_addr 0x0A
#define D6T_cmd 0x4C

int rbuf[35];
float tdata[16];
float t_PTAT;
float top_sum, bottom_sum, left_sum, right_sum, center_sum, center_row_sum;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
  int i;

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {     
    int inByte = Serial.read();     
    if (inByte == 0x0001) {         

      Wire.beginTransmission(D6T_addr);
      Wire.write(D6T_cmd);
      Wire.endTransmission();

      if (WireExt.beginReception(D6T_addr) >= 0) {
        i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
          rbuf[i] = WireExt.get_byte();
        }
        WireExt.endReception();

        t_PTAT = (rbuf[0]+(rbuf[1]<<8))*0.1;
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
          tdata[i]=(rbuf[(i*2+2)]+(rbuf[(i*2+3)]<<8))*0.1;
        }

        output_csv();  
        delay(250);
      }
      top_sum= tdata[0] + tdata[1] + tdata[2] + tdata[3];
      bottom_sum= tdata[12] + tdata[13] + tdata[14] + tdata[15];
      right_sum= tdata[0]+ tdata[4] + tdata[8] + tdata[12];
      left_sum= tdata[3] + tdata[7] + tdata[11] + tdata[15];
      center_sum= tdata[5] + tdata[6] + tdata[9] + tdata[10];
      center_row_sum= tdata[1] + tdata[2] + tdata[5] + tdata[6] + tdata[9] + tdata[10] + tdata[13] + tdata[14];

     if (center_sum>34*4)
    {
      //Serial.flush();
      Serial.write(0x0003);
      delay(100);

    }     
}
  }
}


void output_csv() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print(tdata[i]);
    if (i < 15) {
      Serial.print(",");
    } 
    else {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Attached below is my code in Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import controlP5.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
javax.swing.JOptionPane JOptionPane;

Textlabel myTextlabelA;
boolean canStart = true;
boolean canInput = false;
boolean Start = false;
String typedText = "Comments: ";
PFont font;
int confirm;


float[] tdata = new float[17]; 
float tptat; // PTAT
String portName; 
//int serialport = 0; 

String buf; 
float colourGreen; //change green in relation to temperature 

int lbTemp = 25; //lowest relative temperature
int hbTemp = 40; //highest relative temperature 
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class


void setup() {
  size(600,768);
  background(ControlP5.BLACK);
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM15", 9600);
  myPort.clear();
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  myTextlabelA = cp5.addTextlabel("label")
                    .setText("GUI of Alive Human Detection System.")
                    .setPosition(120,10)
                    .setColorValue(#FFFAF0)
                    .setFont(createFont("Georgia",20))
                    ;

  cp5.addButton("Start")
     .setPosition(115, 670)
     .setSize(100,30)
     ;

  cp5.addButton("Stop")
     .setPosition(375, 670)
     .setSize(100,30)
     ;
}

public void Start(int theValue) {
  println("Initialising...");
  println("Connected.");
  Start = !Start;
}

public void Stop(int theValue) {
  println("Shuting Down...");
  myPort.write(0x02);
  Start = !Start;

}

void draw() {
    if (Start){

    myPort.write(0x01); 
    delay(100); 
    while (myPort.available() > 0) { 
    delay(500);  
    buf = myPort.readString(); 
    myPort.clear();  
    tdata = float(split(buf, ','));  
    for (int i = 0; i <16; i++) { 
    colourGreen = map(tdata[i],lbTemp,hbTemp,255,0);
    fill (255,colourGreen,0);

      if (i == 0)
    { rect(450,64,150,150);}
      else if (i == 1)
    { rect(300,64,150,150);}
      else if (i == 2)
    { rect(150,64,150,150);}
      else if (i == 3)
    { rect(0,64,150,150);}
      else if (i == 4)
    { rect(450,214,150,150);}
      else if (i == 5)
    { rect(300,214,150,150);}
      else if (i == 6)
    { rect(150,214,150,150);}
      else if (i == 7)
    { rect(0,214,150,150);}
      else if (i == 8)
    { rect(450,364,150,150);}
      else if (i == 9)
    { rect(300,364,150,150);}
      else if (i == 10)
    { rect(150,364,150,150);}
      else if (i == 11)
    { rect(0,364,150,150);}
      else if (i == 12)
    { rect(450,514,150,150);}
      else if (i == 13)
    { rect(300,514,150,150);}
      else if (i == 14)
    { rect(150,514,150,150);}
      else if (i == 15)
    { rect(0,514,150,150); }

    if (tdata[i]<5) {fill(255);} else {fill(0);}
      if (i ==0)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),525, 139);}
      else if (i == 1)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),375, 139);
      }
      else if (i == 2)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 225, 139);
      }
      else if (i == 3)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),75, 139); 
      }
      else if (i == 4)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 525, 289); 
      }
      else if (i == 5)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 375, 289);  
      }
      else if (i == 6)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 225, 289);  
      }
      else if (i == 7)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 75, 289); 
      }
      else if (i == 8)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 525, 439);
      }
      else if (i == 9)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 375, 439);  
      }
      else if (i == 10)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 225, 439);
      }
      else if (i == 11)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 75, 439);
      }
      else if (i == 12)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 525, 592);  
      }
      else if (i == 13)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 375, 592); 
      }
      else if (i == 14)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 225, 592);
      }
      else if (i == 15)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 75, 592);  
      }
    }
    delay(250);
    CheckSerial();  
  }

    }

}

void CheckSerial()
{  
    confirm = myPort.read(); 
    if (confirm == 0x03)
  {
  int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Human found? Please Confirm!!", "Alert!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  {
  //futher action
  }
  }
}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Have you tried displaying the string you are receiving in order to confirm it's correct?

Comment: Okay! i will try again. =) thanks! @Majenko

Comment: @Majenko I tried to change my code a bit but still no positive result. Whenever it detected 32*4, Arduino should be sending `Serial.print("found");` to processing and processing should be reading the string "found" and then showing a popup window in result. 

In real scenario, when it meet the condition, and Arduino started to `Serial.print ("found")` , I got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException :1` in processing and the program is not responding after that. I have no idea where seems to be the problem. D: Any suggestion on how to improve these?